# Azure pipeline doesn't triggers after completion of previous pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, triggers, azure-pipelines, azure-triggers

In Azure DevOps I have 2 pipelines let's say Pipeline A and Pipeline B. Pipeline A is scheduled to run daily. Upon successful completion of Pipeline A I want to trigger Pipeline B.

I've added the snippet that should trigger Pipeline B upon successful completion of Pipeline A. But it doesn't work. How can I fix that?

```
trigger: none

resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: AliasA
    source: Pipeline A  # Name of the pipeline that triggers this pipeline
    trigger: 
      branches:
      - branch_prod  # Branches that will trigger this pipeline
```

Comment: Did you try add an `include:` in the `branches:` collection? See more guidance [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops#branch-filters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: AliasA # Name of the pipeline resource.
    source: PipelineA # The name of the pipeline referenced by this pipeline resource.
    project: Project # Required only if the source pipeline is in another project
    trigger: true # Run xx pipeline when any run of yyy completes
```

Comment: This solution is not branch specific. Irrespective of the pipeline completion on any branch the trigger is activated on prod branch,